# Linkedin webhooks event subscription not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, linkedin-api, webhooks

I've been stuck on this issue for some time now, I am trying to subscribe to Linkedin's webhook using ngrok for testing on localhost, and have been trying for some time now, i have tried using encode uri's as well but still running into error, I have verified that the **APP_ID**, **profileId** and **organizationId** i'm using are correct, but still i get the same error. I have also tried using the Restli protocol that linkedin suggests in their documentation but to no avail.

```
let url = `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/eventSubscriptions/(developerApplication:urn:li:developerApplication:${config.IN.APP_ID},user:urn:li:person:${profileId},entity:urn:li:organization:${organizationId},eventType:ORGANIZATION_SOCIAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS)`;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request(
        {
          url,
          method: 'PUT',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            // 'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
          },
          json: {
            webhook: "https://url.ngrok.io/api/v1/webhook/linkedin/callback"
          },
        },
        (err, response, body) => {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          } else {
            resolve(body);
          }
        },
      );
    });
```

I have been receiving this error constantly no matter what I try, I have tried sending the url like this:

- [https://api.linkedin.com/v2/eventSubscriptions/(developerApplication:urn:li:developerApplication:{${config.IN.APP_ID}},user:urn:li:person:{${profileId}},entity:urn:li:organization:{${organizationId}},eventType:ORGANIZATION_SOCIAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS)](https://api.linkedin.com/v2/eventSubscriptions/(developerApplication:urn:li:developerApplication:%7B$%7Bconfig.IN.APP_ID%7D%7D,user:urn:li:person:%7B$%7BprofileId%7D%7D,entity:urn:li:organization:%7B$%7BorganizationId%7D%7D,eventType:ORGANIZATION_SOCIAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS))
- [https://api.linkedin.com/v2/eventSubscriptions/${encodeURIComponent((developerApplication:urn:li:developerApplication:${config.IN.APP_ID},user:urn:li:person:${profileId},entity:urn:li:organization:${organizationId},eventType:ORGANIZATION_SOCIAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS))](https://api.linkedin.com/v2/eventSubscriptions/$%7BencodeURIComponent((developerApplication:urn:li:developerApplication:$%7Bconfig.IN.APP_ID%7D,user:urn:li:person:$%7BprofileId%7D,entity:urn:li:organization:$%7BorganizationId%7D,eventType:ORGANIZATION_SOCIAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS)))

**All I receive is this error**

> '{"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Unpermitted fields present in RESOURCE_KEY: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/key]","status":403}'

Any help would be appreciated, I have been stuck on this for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

The request seems to be OK , but the method should be GET (not PUT)

Answer (score 1):

LinkedIn webhooks [does not support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/api-guide/webhook-validation) ngrok URIs

Answer (score 0):

One thing is to check which ID are you using for application_id. The application ID is the one in the url - `https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps/<id from here>/settings`
. You need to use and uncomment the header for Restli.
I'd say that your url needs to look like this, as this is from their original POSTMAN collection.

`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/eventSubscriptions/(developerApplication:urn%3Ali%3AdeveloperApplication%3A{{application_id}},user:urn%3Ali%3Aperson%3A{{person_id}},entity:urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A{{organization_id}},eventType:ORGANIZATION_SOCIAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS)`

You can validate here, their full collection - https://www.postman.com/linkedin-developer-apis/workspace/e781b3ac-4101-4d60-8981-afcb4812623d/request/16069442-9d0bf046-ea81-4af0-9515-d07246a0ab39

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me:

I encoded the parameters and add version to headers
and instead of `.../rest/..` I used `.../v2/...`

```
public function subscribeToWebhook($userId, $organizationId, $token)
{
  $webhookUrl = 'LINK WEBHOOK';

  $developerAppId = env('DEVELOPER_App_Id');//id from url https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps/--id--/webhooks

  $developerApplicationId = urlencode("urn:li:developerApplication:$developerAppId");

  $personId = urlencode("urn:li:person:$userId");

  $organizationId = urlencode($organizationId);

  $apiUrl = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/eventSubscriptions/(developerApplication:$developerApplicationId,user:$personId,entity:$organizationId,eventType:ORGANIZATION_SOCIAL_ACTION_NOTIFICATIONS)";
        
  $body = [
    "webhook" => "https://rs.sparrowmailing.com/webhook/linkedin"
  ];

  $response = Http::withHeaders([
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'X-Restli-Protocol-Version' => '2.0.0',
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
  ]) -> put($apiUrl,$body);

  return  $response->getStatusCode();
}
```